# Multi language support for an Android device

Tags: android

How do I support my Android device for multiple languages?  I have created a application in Android that dynamically switches between two languages(namely English and Marathi).Every thing works fine in the emulator.  However when I install my application on my Android device the text does not change into the Marathi language.  I have included the Shivaji.ttf file required for the Marathi language in the assets folder of the project.

Please help.

Comment: did you read this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html ?

Comment: yes i have done it and the prject runs fine on emulator the only issue is it does not display characters in marathi on my device.So do i need to add any files on my device externally?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the locale on the device to marathi. There are many free apps that let you easily change the locale.

Comment: can u plese brief me on it.how do i do that.

Comment: Install this app - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mhoffs.customlocale&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5taG9mZnMuY3VzdG9tbG9jYWxlIl0.

Add custom locale, choose language from list